# Partial grouping inside a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For statistical analysis purpose, I would like to regroup some rows inside a data frame based on their values.

What I have:

| number | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 57 |
| 12 | 59 |
| 01 | 68 |
| 12 | 66 |
| 101 | 55 |
| 47 | 61 |
| 05 | 60 |
| 288 | 67 |

The desired output would be, for example, to regroup every latitude above 66 (66+67+68) in a single category 66+ and the desired output would be like this:

| number | latitude | new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 57 | 57 |
| 12 | 59 | 59 |
| 01 | 68 | 66+ |
| 12 | 66 | 66+ |
| 101 | 55 | 55 |
| 47 | 61 | 61 |
| 05 | 60 | 60 |
| 288 | 67 | 66+ |

I do not want to use an if loop because I feel that it is not really R friendly.
I would also like to keep the initial column, that way I can try different combinations later on.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that your "new" column will be character, not numeric anymore (so you cannot compute mean, sum...). Use something like `with(df1, ifelse(latitude >=66, 66, latitude))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option `mutate` and `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(latitude >= 66, "66+", latitude))
```

Output:

```
  number latitude new
1     30       57  57
2     12       59  59
3     01       68 66+
4     12       66 66+
5    101       55  55
6     47       61  61
7     05       60  60
8    288       67 66+
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(number = c("30","12","01","12","101","47","05","288"),
                 latitude = c(57,59,68,66,55,61,60,67))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
df1$new <- df1$latitude
df1$new[df1$latitude >=66] <- "66+"
```

---

or with `ifelse`

```
df1$new <- with(df1, ifelse(latitude >=66, "66+", latitude))
```

-output

```
> df1
  number latitude new
1     30       57  57
2     12       59  59
3      1       68 66+
4     12       66 66+
5    101       55  55
6     47       61  61
7      5       60  60
8    288       67 66+
```

---

Also, as @Mael commented about the type of 'new' column, if we want to preserve the type, can also use `pmin`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(new = pmin(latitude, 66))
   number latitude new
1     30       57  57
2     12       59  59
3      1       68  66
4     12       66  66
5    101       55  55
6     47       61  61
7      5       60  60
8    288       67  66
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~"number",  ~"latitude",
        30, 57,
        12, 59,
        01, 68,
        12, 66,
        101,55,
        47, 61,
        05, 60,
        288,67) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    new = if_else(latitude > 66,
                  "66+",
                  as.character(latitude)))
```